# How do I access a member of a list within a data.frame based on a column in the data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame, as below:

```
x <- structure(list(tsv_level = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2), tsv_payout = structure(list(
    c(0, 700, 1400, 2100, 2800), c(0, 300, 600, 900, 1200), c(0, 
    300, 600, 900, 1200), c(0, 3000, 6000, 9000, 12000), c(0, 
    700, 1400, 2100, 2800), c(0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000)), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("tsv_level", 
"tsv_payout"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like to create a 3rd column that returns the `tsv_levelth` element of each list within `tsv_payout`.

I can do this individually by doing this for row 1: `x$tsv_payout[[1]][2]`, and `x$tsv_payout[[2]][3]` for row 2, but how can I do this for all rows in the data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "hide" the loop with

```
x$v = with(x, mapply(`[[`, tsv_payout, tsv_level))
```

or similar with `transform`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Is it possible to write this within dplyr/mutate? This step is in a chain of mutate commands I'm performing.

Comment: @multiphrenic I think so. `x %>% mutate(v = mapply(\`[[\`, tsv_payout, tsv_level))` seems to work. I'm not sure what the dplyr philosophy regarding list columns is, but you might want to check out other related packages (like tidyr has some sort of "unnest" for list columns, and purrr is somehow related to lists... I only know dplyr myself).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I can work with that. Looks like `rowwise()` might also be helpful here: "ts main impact is to allow you to work with list-variables in summarise and mutate without having to use [[1]]. This makes summarise() on a rowwise tbl effectively equivalent to plyr’s ldply."

Comment: @multiphrenic Yeah, in principle, rowwise should be good here. In practice, though, I've often seen it (somehow) make things very slow. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Frank's answer works, and only relies on base R, but it also looks like rowwise() in the `dplyr` package will work here.

```
x %>% rowwise() %>%
    mutate(v = tsv_payout[tsv_level])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as good as @Frank's solution but it also does the job:

```
x$v <- sapply(seq_along(x$tsv_level), function(i) x$tsv_payout[[i]][x$tsv_level[i]])
```